# How can I allow only specified functions to be executed and disable all others?

Tags: php

I am planning on allowing certain (registered & vetted) users to post php code and/or upload a php file that I will execute in a sandbox environment.

I am aware of how much a bad idea this sounds and the possible security holes I could open.

I'm also going to be doing things like setting strict, short execution times, max runs of a script per day, running the webserver user as unprivileged, et cetera.

I'm aware that I can disallow usage of certain functions in php.ini, but I want to know if it's possible to disable all functions (without putting every single one in php.ini) but allow the use of certain functions that I have vetted and think are safe to allow?

Comment: You could get_defined_functions() and remove the ones you want them to use before disabling the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/index.html) extension which allows you to **whitelist** functions that you want to allow.

See Suhosin's [suhosin.executor.func.whitelist](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.executor.func.whitelist) configuration option.

> **suhosin.executor.func.whitelist**
>
> Comma separated whitelist of functions that are allowed to be called.
>   If the whitelist is empty the blacklist is evaluated, otherwise
>   calling a function not in the whitelist will terminate the script and
>   get logged.